# The word that meant "a small desire, less serious than a dream, goal, passion or a desire." What was it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I distinctly remember the word having the connotations of a weak desire, a very passing dream, momentary wish or a capricious desire. I can also recall that it had 2 or 3 syllables.

It probably ended with the character "E."

Example sentences:
1) Throughout the day I have many Xs, but none of them come to fruition.

2) A goal is serious thing, it keeps you on track. An X is just something I would like to accomplish but it is not important enough to justify my efforts.

3) If only more people paid due attention to Xs, they would see the light of the day. But alas, they dismiss it casually.

Comment: Could you supply a sample sentence to show the word usage, please? Single word requests are required to have them now. Thanks.

Comment: How can you remember it ended with the letter "e"? Normally, in that position, that letter is silent.

Comment: many here consider ir off-topic to help you find THE word you seek.

Comment: In the absence of any inspiration I've been looking for synonyms online. Might it be "allure"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I used to have 5 huge notebooks full of words and articles. When I moved out of old house, I lost some of them, so I cannot revisit those. However, I always remember some aspect of the word, and in this case I recall it being 4 to 5 character long and probably ending in an "e." I think I will hunt for it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up rare and [wonderful words](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/weird-and-wonderful-words/) on [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/velleity), I unearthed the following

> **velleity**
>   A wish or inclination not strong enough to lead to action.
>   *‘the notion intrigued me, but remained a velleity’*
>   **Origin**
>   Early 17th century: from medieval Latin *velleitas*, from Latin *velle* ‘to wish’.

Comment: Finally, peace.

Answer (score 2):

Could "**whimsy**"(or plural "**whimsies**") be the word that you seek? The word loosely follows your full description. There are alternative spellings (i.e. "**whimsey**" or "**whimseys**") that might represent your "recollection" of an "E" at the end - again loosely. Anyway, as a deductive guess, I thought it was worth offering.

> Throughout the day I have many **whimsies**, but none of them come to
> fruition.
>
> Throughout the day I have many **whimsical ideas**, but none of them come to
> fruition.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/whimsey

Answer (score 1):

For words ending in *e*:

**urge**  (meets four-letters recollection)

> If you have an urge to do or have something, you have a strong wish to
> do or have it. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/urge)

**impulse** (meets two-syllables recollection)

> An impulse is a sudden desire to do something.
>
> *Unable to resist the impulse, he glanced at the sea again.*  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/impulse)

Answer (score 0):

**Caprice** is two syllables and ends in E. It describes a [sudden, impulsive, and unmotivated desire](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caprice):

> : a sudden, impulsive, and seemingly unmotivated notion or action

A **[whim](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whim)** is a key synonym I would have suggested if *caprice* didn't fit:

> : a capricious or eccentric and often sudden idea or turn of the mind : fancy

I mention that because sometimes the words can work together (as "[whims and caprices](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/translation/whims+and+caprices.html)"). Hence:

> Throughout the day I have many whims, but none of them come to fruition.
>
> A goal is a serious thing. It keeps you on track. A caprice is just something I would like to accomplish but it is not important enough to justify my efforts.
>
> If only more people paid due attention to whims and caprices, they would see the light of day. But alas, they dismiss it casually.

Answer (score -1):

Is the word you’re looking for “fancy“?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just look at the other answers to this question: They ***quote*** dictionary definitions and link to their sources.  Answers that don't do that are often deleted.